# Need a column within a table to maintain data manually entered after data refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a table in excel which is populated using a ODBC connection to a SQL database.
This table contains orders and the status of each order (the status is changed by a third party program), I have added additional columns to the table through power query however these are all conditional and have formula to populate the cell.

I am wanting to add a couple of columns to the table which would allow me to enter text data to the cells and keep them saved in excel. Currently when I add a column to the table and enter any text it is removed upon the next refresh, what I would like to happen is for this data to be maintained despite the query being refreshed... I would also only like the additional columns to be 'persistent' and not the other columns in the table as these contain data which does need to be refreshed.

Is this possible to do without having multiple tables and merging them?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and include screenshots of sample data and your preferred output.

Comment: If U are using MS-Query,,, or Query in Access or Power Query then you may add as many new columns based on aggregate function or calculations !

Answer (score 1):

## Yes!

*(... but... technically no. :-) )*

Assuming your original query has a primary key column called "PrimaryKey", create a new query by referencing your original query. Call it "QueryPlusManual". Load QueryPlusManual to your workbook.

In Excel, edit the results to add a column named "ManualColumn" and put in a few values.

Create a new query called "PrimaryKeyAndManual" with the following code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="QueryPlusManual"]}[Content],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"PrimaryKey", "ManualColumn"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

What this does is reads from the worksheet, *not* from the QueryPlusManual *query*!

Now comes the part where we put the cart before the horse. Edit your QueryPlusManual query and

- merge PrimaryKeyAndManual (left-outer join), then
- expand your merge to add the manual column.

The last few lines of your QueryPlusManual query should look like this:

```
    #"Merged PrimaryKeyAndManual" = Table.NestedJoin(#"PREVIOUSLINENAME",PrimaryKeyAndManual,{"PrimaryKey"},"PrimaryKeyAndManual",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded PrimaryKeyAndManual" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged PrimaryKeyAndManual", "PrimaryKeyAndManual", {"ManualColumn"}, {"ManualColumn"})
in
    #"Expanded PrimaryKeyAndManual"
```

So in effect, you *are* merging two tables, it's just that one of them happens to already be (the previous version of) your output!