# Updating weekly Excel reports

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get an Excel project update every week from HQ.  This report has info I don't need and lacks info I do need.  I would like to be able to format a modified version with the above additions and deletions, then somehow have it update weekly from the information I receive on the weekly report from HQ.
So, if I add 5 columns that I need and enter the info manually, I'd like to be able to keep that format and have it update to the latest info for for the columns on the HQ report.

Any suggestions?

Comment: create a template where you paste in the report you receive each week as a sub set, then the main report pulls through only what you need, an contains any helper columns, better than this would be to have the report form part of a data model

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it's a file on the fileshare that HQ updates. Assuming it's email instead, though, the workaround is simple, just always save it to the same file path every time you get an update.

Then, in a new Excel file, click **Data - Get & Transform - New Query - From File - From Workbook** from the ribbon and get your data from HQ. In the dialog box, click "Edit" instead of "Load".

This should open a new window. If all you want is specific columns, click the **Home - Manage Columns - Choose Columns** button from the ribbon and make sure only the columns you want are selected. You can filter your query as well.

Click "Close & Load" and your new worksheet should have the data from HQ that you want.

Unfortunately, if you add columns to the table that you've just created, you'll lose them every time you refresh your query. For a query that only refreshes some of the columns but leaves others editable, you'll need to dive into Power Query a little further and try a technique I've discovered and documented [here](https://superuser.com/a/1570462).

Answer (score -1):

You can enable tracking changes in Excel workbook.

Review tab > Changes group > Track changes > In the Highlight Changes dialog box, check the option – Track changes while editing.

Repeat the first 4 steps from above later to highlight changes. (Click the Highlight changes in Track changes)

Applies for MS word too.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Can you explain? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.